# Finding string in optional list of lists

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have a list of 'Blocks' that could be null. Each of the blocks contains a list of names that also could be null. I'm trying to find if any of the names in all the blocks is the word "blurb".

I have the following code which does work:

```
private boolean containsText(List<Blocks> blocks) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(blocks)
            .map(Collection::stream)
            .map(o -> o.map(Blocks::getNames))
            .map(e -> e.anyMatch(names -> names != null && names.contains("blurb")))
            .orElse(false);
}
```

But since getNames could return null I have to check for it in the next statement. I could wrap it in another Optional at that point, but then I would end up with an 
 `Optional<Stream<Optional<List<String>>>>`

Using `names -> names != null`
seems cleaner? Or is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: One of your problem is the design where you say, *"I have a list of 'Blocks' that could be null"*, you should fix it to return an empty list for such representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simpler variant without the use of `Optional` would just be :

```
private boolean containsText(List<Blocks> blocks) {
    return blocks != null && blocks.stream()
            .map(Blocks::getNames)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .anyMatch(list -> list.contains("blurb"));
}
```

*Note*: One of your problems is the design where you say, *"I have a list of 'Blocks' that could be null"*, you should fix it to return an empty list for such representation and then get rid of the `null` check in the above code.

Answer (score 4):

With Java-9 you can use `Stream.ofNullable` as follows:

```
public boolean containsText(List<Blocks> blocks) {
    return Stream.ofNullable(blocks)
            .flatMap(b -> b.stream().map(Blocks::getNames).filter(Objects::nonNull))
            .anyMatch(s -> s.contains("blurb"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using `Optional` for `null` check you can use ternary operator to check `blocks` is null and simply return `false` if it is null, else stream the `blocks` list and check for string

```
return Objects.isNull(blocks) ? false : blocks.stream()
                                             .map(Blocks::getNames)
                                             .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                             .anyMatch(list->list.contains("blurb"));
```

You can also add simple null for existing code

```
private boolean containsText(List<Blocks> blocks) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(blocks)
        .map(Collection::stream)
        .map(o -> o.map(Blocks::getNames).filter(Objects::nonNull))
        .map(e -> e.anyMatch(names -> names.contains("blurb")))
        .orElse(false);
}
```

Comment: Or you could simplify further `.map(o -> o.map(Blocks::getNames).filter(Objects::nonNull))
                .orElse(Stream.of())
                .anyMatch(names -> names.contains("blurb"));` That said, the [solution with `Stream.ofNullable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60405267/1746118) reads better still. In the other case, using [ternary operator can be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60406087/1746118) as well.

Comment: Replace `Objects.isNull(blocks) ? false : …` with `blocks != null && …` Using `Objects.isNull(…)` instead of a straight-forward null check is a similar overuse as using `Optional` for this job. And the ternary operator is obsolete (generally, any logical operator combining an expression with a boolean literal is obsolete)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Holger but Naman already posted the answer using that approach, so i if make change now mine will predicted as duplicate answer and that's the reason i haven't updated the answer, but i have one question on `Object.isNull` so as a developer to increase the more readability i prefer `Objects.isNull` instead of hard coding `blocks != null` is it not recommended ? or can you explain is there any perfomance impact ?

Comment: How is `Objects.isNull(blocks)` more readable than `blocks == null`? We could replace every builtin operator by a static method like replacing `a + b` with `Integer.sum(a, b)`, but what would we gain by that change? The [documentation of `isNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull-java.lang.Object-) clearly states that its purpose is to be used as `Objects::isNull`…